# iptables allow A -> B:22 , B -> everywhere:22

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I want iptables rules that let a server allow incoming ssh from a specific host and at the same time this server can connect ssh on any destination, then block any other in/out traffic

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

then add:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -s 100.101.102.103/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "SSH inbound" -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "SSH outbound" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "General SSH outbound" -j ACCEPT
```

Replace 100.101.102.103 with any IP address you need

Comment: Default deny policies might be useful at all.  Nothing here does any dropping.

Comment: Alan, I think these rules don't effect as you drop nothing.

Comment: I was trying to be as relevant as can be.